# Export result of a forEach function

Tags: meteor

I've got a `forEach` function on a collection

```
const docs = Docs.find({"owner": userId}, {fields: {"recipients": 1}});

docs.forEach(({ recipients }) => {
        var docsRecipients = recipients;
        //log #1
        console.log(docsRecipients);
    });

var  docsRecipientsFinal = docsRecipients;
//log #2
console.log(docsRecipientsFinal);
```

The #1 `console.log` returns correct results, not the #2 (of course, this is just to be understood).

How can I export the result of the forEach function, for using it outside of the loop ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want an array

```
const docs = Docs.find({"owner": userId}, {fields: {"recipients": 1}});
var docsRecipients = [];  //define it outside the forEach scope

docs.forEach(({ recipients }) => {

       docsRecipients.push(recipients);
       console.log(docsRecipients);


    });

var  docsRecipientsFinal = docsRecipients;  
//log #2
console.log(docsRecipientsFinal);
```

Update :

Just use

```
var docRecipients = Docs.find({"owner": userId}, {fields: {"recipients": 1}}).fetch();
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. An array is what I wanted. Could you tell me how to decompose it ? It's an other question, but just in case it's a short instruction...

Comment: @Ontokrat This really isn't necessary in Meteor, just use the cursor's `.fetch()` method (it returns an array of documents). See my example below.

Comment: @jordanwillis yes. I completely agree. I will mention this in the answer. However, I wanted to point out the issue of scoping in the original code, so used the example. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

In Meteor, there is no need to even iterate over the collection, just use the cursor's [`.fetch()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-fetch) method.  It returns an array of documents.

```
const docs = Docs.find({
  "owner": userId
}, {
  fields: {
    "recipients": 1
  }
}).fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

the scope of `docsRecipients` is within the `foreach` block, to access the `docsRecipients` value declare it as a global variable above `foreach`,also this will store the last index value of `foreach`.

[sample foreach](http://jsfiddle.net/kavinhuh/Lpq9wt97/1/)

```
 var docsRecipients="";
    docs.forEach(({ recipients }) => {
             docsRecipients = recipients;
            //log #1
            console.log(docsRecipients);
        });

    var  docsRecipientsFinal = docsRecipients;
    //log #2
    console.log(docsRecipientsFinal);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your link is broken.